# Little tweaking of my image slider (adding transition animations)

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi guys a created this image slider and i want to add transition animation, my desired transition is something like
 [this](http://themes.webdevia.com/bathrooms-wordpress-theme/portfolio-style-2-four-columns/)

Also here is my Javascript code:

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
  arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
  arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
  current = 0;

// Clear all images
function reset() {
  for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Init slider
function startSlide() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}

// Show prev
function slideLeft() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
  current--;
}

// Show next
function slideRight() {
  reset();
  sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
  current++;
}

// Left arrow click
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
  }
  slideLeft();
});

// Right arrow click
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
    current = -1;
  }
  slideRight();
});

startSlide();
```

And my html:

```
<div className="Slider">
      <div id="arrow-left" className="arrow"></div>

      <div id="slider">

        <div className="slide slide1">
          <div className="slide-content">
            <span>My vám doručíme kvalitu<br/> na úrovni</span>
            <button>Pozrieť viac</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="slide slide1">
          <div className="slide-content">
            <span>Na tomto slide vám taktiez<br/> doručíme kvalitu</span>
            <button>Pozrieť viac</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div id="arrow-right" className="arrow"></div>
  </div>
```

My javascript may be too long or inefficient but I just starting to get the hang of it also its inspired from youtube but it's work great minus the transition effect

Comment: I don't understand.  What is your exact question?

Comment: Not finding any question mark on your post.. Are you missing something?

Comment: Why is this posted on `stackoverflow.com/questions`?

Comment: Sorry guys i may be a little bit confusing, so my problem is when my slider changes slides or images, there is no transition animation so i want to add it

Comment: So my question is, how to add transitions to slide like from slide 1 to slide 2 to go smooothly